# Conditionally lock / unlock cells in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column A "Mood" with values = Happy or Sad.
I have a column B "Why are you sad?" with values = Stubbed toe, Hungry, Mourning

I want to lock the cell in column B, and unlock it if A = Sad

How?

Thanks!

Comment: You could write a script that triggers based on edit, looks at the cell that was edited (`e.range`) and then sets or unsets the sheet protection based on that. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer via some extra Google searching. This is a YouTube video on how it works, followed by a link to the code in the video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_705816535&feature=iv&src_vid=RkpBms7DKgo&v=rW9T4XZy-7U

https://script.google.com/d/1-U7dOHp6V-mEYqgQPRKDp5Vwx4RCeaWKLO62xVsetNnLmocjHYO80-9_/edit?usp=sharing

What the author does is create some ranges in a different sheet as lookup values, and then populate the select box with the values from the matching column.

```
function depDrop_(range, sourceRange){
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(sourceRange, true).build();
range.setDataValidation(rule);
}
function onEdit (){
var aCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
var aColumn = aCell.getColumn();
if (aColumn == 1 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()){
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
depDrop_(range, sourceRange);
}
else if (aColumn == 2 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()){
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
depDrop_(range, sourceRange);
}
```